# Where with Eloquent Model

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

In Laravel, i have 2 table:

post table:

```
╔════╦══════════════╦══════╗
║ ID ║  CONTENT     ║USERID║
╠════╬══════════════╬══════╣
║  1 ║ Lorem 1      ║  1   ║
║  2 ║ Lorem 2      ║  3   ║
║  3 ║ Lorem 3      ║  1   ║
║  4 ║ Lorem 4      ║  2   ║
╚════╩══════════════╩══════╝
```

And user table:

```
╔════╦════════════════╗
║ ID ║  EMAIL         ║
╠════╬════════════════║
║  1 ║user1@email.com ║
║  2 ║user2@email.com ║
║  3 ║user3@email.com ║
║  4 ║user4@email.com ║
╚════╩════════════════╝
```

I want to select all posts posted by user ID using Laravel.
Post, User Model:

```
#Post Model
class Post extends \Eloquent {
    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('User', 'userid');
    }
}

#User Model
class User extends \Eloquent {
    public function post()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('Post');
    }
}
```

Now, I was select using Laravel Eloquent:

```
$post = Post::with(array(
    'user'  =>  function($query)
    {
        $query->where('email', Input::get('email'));
    }
))->paginate(10);
```

This code will select all post, not by user, and paginate wrong page.
Anyone can help me ?
Thanks so much !

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for the [`whereHas`](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/eloquent#querying-relations) method:

```php
$posts = Post::whereHas('user', function($query)
{
    $query->where('email', Input::get('email'));

})->paginate(10);
```